# How to load components into Craft 3 plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

what is the correct way to load third-party components into Craft 3 plugin I'm developing?

I tried adding

```
$this->setComponents([
    'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => '\yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
            'twitter' => [
                'class' => '\yii\authclient\clients\Twitter'
            ],
            // etc.
        ],
    ]
]);`
```

to plugin's `init()` function, as well as `parent::setComponents`, but both produced same error:

> Unknown component ID: authClientCollection

What am I doing wrong here?